# Fixed position header with slideToggle scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, header, css-position, slidetoggle

I have a Header navigation bar that I want to stick at the top of the page when a user scrolls through the page's content.  The Nav bar is just a logo and you click it to show the actual navigation elements (or links) via jQuery's **slideToggle()**.  When you scroll down the page a ways, and click to toggle the Nav bar, the click action takes the user back to the top of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show-main").click(function() {
        $(".main-navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intaglioman/kENzU/4/).

I want to be able to open the Nav bar from where it sits after scrolling down the page and not have it "pop" back up to the top of the page.  Any suggestions or links or help to point me in the right direction would be **AWESOME**!!!!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#show-main").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".main-navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```